# Concurrency in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When interacting with the database, Entity Framework can suddenly throw an "An operation is already in progress." exception. I have done some testing by sending many concurrent requests and come to the conclusion that this is has to do with some requests sharing the same persistence context. I'm using Entity Framework Core with PostgreSQL.

This is how I've configured EF in my startup class:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<PersistenceContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]);
    });
```

The PersistenceContext is a class with DbSet< ModelType > for each type that I store in the database. The PersistenceContext are injected using dependency injection. An example of a connection string I'm using now is:

```
Server=localhost;User Id=myUser;Password=myPasswordDatabase=myDb;
```

I've also tried to add a `Pooling` flag to the string without any affect.

An example of a simple controller for a web-API that would throw the exception:

```
[Route("example")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private PersistenceContext dbContext;

    public ChannelController(PersistenceContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFoo()
    {
        Model.Foo instance = await (from p in dbContext.Foo
                                    select p).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        return Ok(instance);
    }
}
```

Am I missing out on some details for setting up EF or could this be a framework bug? I'm on RC1-final.

Comment: This looks like it could be a bug, but try upgrading to RC2 first before filing an issue with EF Core as DNX is deprecated.